# How do I build an apk for an Avalonia android app?

Tags: android, apk, avalonia

I'm trying to build an Android app with Avalonia (using Visual Studio 2022 Community on Windows). How do I make a `.apk` file? Building the solution results in the following files created in the `bin\Release\net7.0-android\`:

```
MyApp.Android.dll
MyApp.Android.pdb
MyApp.Android.runtimeconfig.json
MyApp.Android.xml
MyApp.dll
MyApp.pdb
```

... and no APK anywhere. I have tried reading [the manual](https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/next/guides/platforms/android/build-and-run-your-application-on-a-device) but it appears to only explain debugging on an USB-attached and doesn't mention building an installable package.

Comment: It would be helpful if you well us which command(s) you have executed to get this output.

Comment: @Robert I executed no commands, just pressed `Build solution` in Visual Studio.

Comment: That could be the problem. The manual clearly states that you should execute `dotnet run`.

Comment: @Robert yes and no - not clearly. It says "if using console" and offers another option for "if using Visual Studio Code". I do neither and that's why I didn't expect this to apply. As Avalonia provides seemingly robust Visual Studio integration I expected traditional Visual Studio tools to be able to do the job. Nevertheless you are right - `dotnet run` did it.

Comment: There still are a couple of noncritical quirks though:  

Could not extract the MVID from "obj\Debug\net7.0\refint\MyApp.dll". Are you sure it is a reference assembly? ⁂

JAVAC : warning : unknown enum constant Scope.LIBRARY_GROUP_PREFIX [...\MyApp\MyApp.Android\MyApp.Android.csproj] ⁂

System.IO.IOException: ... 'original.pdb' ... being used by another process (unless using Release config) ⁂

Two APKs get bult: com.CompanyName.MyApp.apk won't install (Android says its corrupted) com.CompanyName.MyApp-Signed.apk is Ok once you approve it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Visual Studio, right click on the Android project in the Solution Explorer and go to **Properties**, then to **Android** -> **Options** and ensure the **Android package format** is set to "**apk**".

Next, build the Android-project with the **Release** configuration.

Then right click on the Android-Project and click **Archive...** - this will create an APK. Click **View Archives...** to see previously created apk bundles.

[Similar to how it's done in MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-ad-hoc?view=net-maui-8.0)

Comment: Despite package format being set (by default - I checked and found it already Ok) to apk the way the MAUI manual you linked suggests, this produces a `nupkg` and not an `apk` package. I then went on by the MAUI manual ans clicked `Publish...` but this step failed. I tried going `Archive...` instead and it worked - it produced an APK. However...

Comment: ... However this APK won't install - Android says "App not installed as package appears to be invalid" (using `dotnet run` instead would produce two APKs, one broken the same way, another having a `-Signed` postfix in the name which can be installed Ok once you approve it manually). I then clicked `Distribute...`, chose `Ad Hoc`,  created a Keystore and went on clicking `Save As` - this produced a good installable APK.